# Small Javascript Issue with removing multiple elements from dynamic form

Tags: javascript

Can anyone shed any light on to what I'm doing wrong here if possible?

We have a basic form on a php page with javascript that creates 4 form fields when a button is clicked.

If the button is clicked multiple times then it will keep creating rows of 4 columns. The problem is trying to remove the row (4 elements) if someone clicks the button, I can only ever get it to delete one element where I need it to remove all 4 elements (inputs) in that row,

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var i = 0; /* Set Global Variable i */
function increment() {
    i += 1; /* Function for automatic increment of field's "Name" attribute. */
}

//Function to Remove Form Elements Dynamically
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv) {
    if (childDiv == parentDiv) {
        alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
    } else if (document.getElementById(childDiv)) {
        var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
        parent.removeChild(child);
    } else {
        alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
        return false;
    }
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Name text field.
function nameFunction() {
    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    increment();
    y.setAttribute("Name", "quantityordered_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
    r.appendChild(g);
    r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);


    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "QTY Delivered");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    increment();
    y.setAttribute("Name", "quantitydelivered_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
    r.appendChild(g);
    r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);

    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Description");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    increment();
    y.setAttribute("Name", "description_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
    r.appendChild(g);
    r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);

    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Price ie; £15.00");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    increment();
    y.setAttribute("Name", "price_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_" + i + "')");
    r.appendChild(g);
    r.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i);
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button.
function resetElements() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px; padding-left:30px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="nameFunction()" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
      Add another Item
    </button>
</div>
```

I hope this helps? Please note Iam new to JS and thought this would be a great project to dive into etc.

Many thanks in advance for any advice anyone can give

Comment: You're only removing one element. Are you creating the new `div`'s with the same ID?

Comment: No I think its just creating the elements, possible in a span, this was originally code from a tutorial which i have adapted to suite but there still much to learn about JS lol so not overly sure is the honest answer

Comment: When a new row of 4 inputs is added it assigns an id ie; name_1 name_2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert all 4 inputs into one "container" - and you can remove all of it by removing a container.

```js
var i = 0; /* Set Global Variable i */
function increment() {
    i += 1; /* Function for automatic increment of field's "Name" attribute. */
}

//Function to Remove Form Elements Dynamically
function removeElement(childId) {
    // Simplify form - only need a childId
    if (document.getElementById(childId)) {
        var child = document.getElementById(childId);
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Name text field.
function nameFunction() {

    // Create a container for all 4 inputs
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var containerId = 'id_' + i;
    container.id = containerId;
    increment();

    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Name");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('" + containerId + "')");
    y.setAttribute("Name", "quantityordered_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.appendChild(g);
    container.appendChild(r);
    increment();


    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "QTY Delivered");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('" + containerId + "')");
    y.setAttribute("Name", "quantitydelivered_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.appendChild(g);
    container.appendChild(r);
    increment();

    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Description");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('" + containerId + "')");
    y.setAttribute("Name", "description_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.appendChild(g);
    container.appendChild(r);
    increment();

    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Price ie; £15.00");
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
    g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('" + containerId + "')");
    y.setAttribute("Name", "price_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.appendChild(g);
    container.appendChild(r);
    increment();

    // Append container to form
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(container);
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button.
function resetElements() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="myForm" class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px; padding-left:30px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="nameFunction()" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
      Add another Item
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats amazing!! worked perfectly first time! and the great thing is I actually learned something here, I didnt realise it could be acheived so simply, Many thanks that was really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to place all the four created elements into surrounding `div`, give it an `id` and the remove it by `id`.

But if you want to preserve the current structure you can remove them by a class name.

1) Create a function for generating class name from `i` (assuming that `nameFunction` creates 4 elements):

```
   function getClassName(i) {
        return "name_spans_" + ~~((i - 1)/4);
    }
```

2) Add a class to each generated span after each call to `increment()`:

```
increment(); // after this line
r.className += getClassName(i);
```

3) Modify `onclick` handler to pass `i` of the last generated span:

```
g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm'," + i + ")");
```

4) Modify `removeElement` function to remove all elements with a class name corresponding to passed `i`:

```
function removeElement(parentDiv, i) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
    var children = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(getClassName(i)));

    for (var c = 0; c < children.length; ++c) {
        parent.removeChild(children[c]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My response is similare to @user3153664 one, but i simplifiend the "create element" phase into one function and tryed to clean the code...

```js
var i = 0; /* Set Global Variable i */
function increment() {
  i += 1; /* Function for automatic increment of field's "Name" attribute. */
}

//Function to Remove Form Elements Dynamically
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv) {
  if (childDiv == parentDiv) {
    alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
  } else if (document.getElementById(childDiv)) {
    var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
    parent.removeChild(child);
  } else {
    alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
    return false;
  }
}

function createInputElement(row, placeholder, name) {
  var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
  y.setAttribute("type", "text");
  y.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholder);
  
  var g = document.createElement("IMG");
  g.setAttribute("src", "img/delete.png");
  g.setAttribute("alt", "X");
  y.setAttribute("Name", name);
  
  var r = document.createElement('span');
  r.appendChild(y);
  g.onclick = function() { removeElement('myForm', row.getAttribute('id')) };
  r.appendChild(g);
  
  return r;
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Name text field.
function nameFunction() {
  var row = document.createElement('P'); // a set of 4 elements to be delete together 
 
  increment();
  row.setAttribute("id", "id_" + i); // set the row id with the value of i
  row.appendChild(createInputElement(row, 'Name', 'quantityordered_'+i ));
  
  increment();
  row.appendChild(createInputElement(row, 'QTY Delivered', 'quantitydelivered_'+i ));
  
  increment();
  row.appendChild(createInputElement(row, 'Description', 'description_'+i ));
  
  increment();
  row.appendChild(createInputElement(row, 'Price ie; £15.00', 'price_'+i ));
    
  document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(row);
}

//Functions that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button.
function resetElements() {
  document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px; padding-left:30px;">
    <button type="button" onclick="nameFunction()" class="btn btn-info">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add another Item
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: no problem! we can enhance this code so much more, but I don't  know exactly your needs... :)